# Rails with Mongoid : Generate a error when authentication fails

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am newbie to Rails and Mongoid. I am trying to create a login page. The problem is I am not able to give out a error messages if there is a username or password error. Below is my code.

Model user.rb

```
def self.authenticate(login, pass)

 if user = first(:conditions => {:username => login})

   return user if user.password==(pass)

end

   return false

end
```

Controller user_auth.rb

```
def login

   if  request.post? && @user = User.authenticate(params[:user][:username],params[:user][:password])

 redirect_to(:controller => 'posts')

   else

 @user = User.new()
   end
end
```

View login.html.erb

```
 <% form_for(@user,:url => { :action => "login" } ) do |d| %>
   <% if @user.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
    <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>

    <ul>
     <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
   <% end %>
    </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>

 <p> Your Name: <%= d.text_field :username %><br />  </p>
 <p> Password: <%= d.password_field :password %><br/></p>
 <p><%=d.submit "Login" %></p>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that on authentication failure, you instantiate a new user with no args "@user = User.new()", and then look for @user.errors.  It's a guess that your new user doesn't set any errors by default (why should it?).  From your problem statement, it's clear that your error condition is not communicated correctly.  It would be cleaner and more obvious to set @errors in your controller and check @errors in your view rather than add indirection through a new user instance.